# Return a File to download on LinkButton click

Tags: c#, sftp

I am uploading my files to a **sftp server**, which users should be able to download later. Now how they are going to download is, I am showing the files in a grid, with their Names (saved in DB) as LinkButtons.

On the linkbuttons click I am going to download the file from sftp server to a local folder on the server and then, here I directly want to give the file to the user. The link button doesnt have a hard link.

Also, there is no restriction of filetype or size. Please can you suggest anything that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the second problem (sending the locally downloaded file), you basically send the file back to the client as the response to the click event:

From [How to send a file to a client so a Download dialog will open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252135/how-to-send-a-file-to-a-client-so-a-download-dialog-will-open):

```
string pdfPath = MapPath("mypdf.pdf");
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment; filename=" + pdfPath );
Response.TransmitFile(pdfPath);
Response.End();
```

Comment: That is the problem actually, there is no restriction on the file type.

Comment: Or is there no other option than looking at the types and hardcoding the Responce.ContentType for each filetype(atleast the one commonly used)?

Comment: application/octet-stream is fine for file downloading unless you want a specific action in the other end. Eg for pdf file application/octet-stream will download, while application/pdf will tell browser to open pdf file.

Comment: Will the users be able to download a .ABC file as something.ABC, like would it populate ABC in "Save As Type" field in the download file dialogue?

Comment: afaik, yes, as long as you fill in the filename in the header correctly.

Comment: I tried the above code in gridview row command event, and it didnt work.

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with gridview. Maybe you need to redirect to a url that does the download. Response.Redirect("DownloadPage.aspx?Name=somefile");

Comment: The above code helped, and thanks "sphair". I was trying to do a postback in updatepanel (:)). Used _doPostBack and coded the above snippet in the page_load event, and gave the user the file he wanted to download.

Comment: Following on from Taha's comment, I had to use `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(myLinkButton);` when inside an UpdatePanel otherwise it would not work.